# sscanf overflowing in destination adresses

Tags: c, string, parsing, embedded

I am parsing an IP string in C and I am using the following line:

```
typedef unsigned char UI_8;
UI_8 TFTP_IP_NUMBERS[4];
UI_8 TFTP_IP[15]; // Should  be something lige "192.168.12.30" 
sscanf(TFTP_IP , "%d.%d.%d.%d", TFTP_IP_NUMBERS[0],
                                TFTP_IP_NUMBERS[1],
                                TFTP_IP_NUMBERS[2], 
                                TFTP_IP_NUMBERS[3]);
```

The line works great (it is parsing correctly) but it is writting in places it should not be writting.In the memory addresses with "XX" the values are stored correctly, but the memory addresses with "AA" are overridden withs "00".

```
XX XX XX XX AA AA AA
```

What could be causing this behaviour? How can this be avoided

I am expecting to have:

```
TFTP_IP_NUMBERS = [192,168,12,30]
```

Comment: You are trying to assign digits to character values? `%d`. Try `%d%*c` and let me know what you get (you should get the same, but this is forcing it to ignore characters. So when that is confirmed. Try `%c%*d` for where it is characters only, not sure if C is smart enough to do `(%d.%d.%d.%d)%*c`. Give it a try.

Comment: Please try to create an [mcve] to show us. For example, what is the *exact* contents of `TFTP_IP`? And what is `TFTP_IP_NUMBERS`?

Comment: Is TFTP_IP_NUMBERS[0] contains the address where the parsed value from the sscanf to be written? if you want to write to this array then you have to give as &TFTP_IP_NUMBERS[0]. so on to all the variables address to be passed. refer to the sscanf() man page.

Comment: having tried with &TFTP_IP_NUMBERS[0] and the result is the same

Comment: You need to go back to your book, tutorial or class notes to read about `scanf` (and family) again. How do they tell you to pass arguments to `scanf`? And what kind of type does the `"%d"` specifier parse? How many bits are that type? At the very least please see e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). A good compiler should have warned you, and if not then enable more verbose warnings.

Comment: @Joel I have tried your solutions. Trying with %c%*d and the result was that it returned only "1". The option (%d.%d.%d.%d)%*c did not make any assignation to the result vector. And the %d%*c%d%*c%d%*c%d%*c works but also have the overflow

Comment: @xing Your solution is the correct. Add it as an answer please.  The reason why there were only 3 overflow bytes was that the second number was overwriting three of the the overflown characters from the first number, the third number was overwriting the 3 overflown from the second one and so on.

Comment: Aah (i), of course, misunderstood the question. its `%hhd` you want to use as @xing suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier processes an `int` you are passing it a *smaller* `unsigned char`, and also not correctly passing a pointer (two errors).

```
int ip_parts[4];
sscanf( ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &ip_parts[0], 
                           &ip_parts[1],
                           &ip_parts[2],
                           &ip_parts[4] ) ;
```

You would write directly to `unisigned char` using the `%hhd` format specifier, but the `hh` size modifier is not supported by all libraries and will serve to make the code less portable.  The fact that you have used a type UI8_t suggests that you might not have the standard uint8_t and so are possibly not using a C99 compliant library or compiler - in which case `%hhu` may also not work.

```
UI8 ip_parts[4];
sscanf( ip, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", &ip_parts[0], 
                                   &ip_parts[1],
                                   &ip_parts[2],
                                   &ip_parts[4] ) ;
```